# Google Apps Script - 6 min Time limit

Tags: google-apps-script

I've a Google Apps Script. It's a long script and takes about 25-30min to execute. I created this script back in Jan / Feb timeframe and if I recall correctly I didn't face this 6min limit issue at that time. After writing the script initially in Jan / Feb it's today I ran it again and ran into 6min time limit issue. After search I found the 6 min limitation has been there for a while.

So, what's not clear to me why / how my script was able to complete successfully when I originally wrote it in Jan / Feb?

Any advise is appreciated.

Regards,
Vikas.

Comment: Based upon what I can see of the script it looks okay to me.

Comment: Did you change your G Suite account?